# Dataframe has subscription purchase history. Trying to show subsequent subscriptions purchased

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataframe with subscription term purchase records. For example, individuals (identified by their account numbers) have originally purchased 3, 6, 9, 12, 16, 18 or 24 month subscriptions. I am interested in determining how many purchasers of, e.g, 3 month subscriptions went to purchases another 3 month subscription or 6, 9, 12, 16, 18 or 24 month period subscription.

Here is a simplified version of the dataframe.

```
user_id     purch date          Product 
        
65587578    2018-03-01 01:21:12     3 month subscription
65587578    2018-06-07 19:39:56     6 month subscription
65587578    2019-03-07 11:39:56     12 month subscription

65785442    2018-03-07 19:39:56     3 month subscription
65785442    2018-09-07 11:39:16     6 month subscription
65785442    2019-09-01 10:21:11     6 month subscription

89808622    2018-03-01 02:19:0      3 month subscription
89808622    2018-06-07 19:39:56     1 month subscription
89808622    2019-07-07 12:31:46     12 month subscription
```

Here is some code I have to extract, for example, all the 3 month subscriptions:

`repurchases.loc[repurchases['product'] == '3 month subscription']`

which could produce

```
user_id     purch date      Product 
65587578    2019-03-07 11:39:56 3 month subscription
89808622    2019-07-07 12:31:46 3 month subscription
and so on..
```

But what I really want to do is group the account numbers that made an initial purchase of e.g., a 3 month subscription (using the purch date), count them, and determine how many other other subscriptions they bought subsequently such as 1 month subscription, 6 month subscription, and so on.

I am struggling with how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating this. I used the following to identify user_ids with multiple purchases (showing up more than once in the dataframe)

```
#All purchases users whose first purchase is 3 month subscription
df_all = df[df.duplicated(['user_id'], keep=False)]
df_all_sorted = df_all.sort_values(['user_id', 'purch_date'], ascending=True)
df_all_first = df_all_sorted.groupby('user_id'], as_index=False).nth(0)
df_first_xmo = df_all_first[df_all_first['product'] == '3 month subscription']

#Prepare date-sorted dataframes to extract subsequent purchases where first purchase is 3 months subscription."
df_all_withxmosPurchFirst = df_all[df_all.p_paid_user_id.isin(df_first_xmo.user_id)]
df_all_withxmosPurchFirst_sorted = df_all_withxmosPurchFirst.sort_values(['user_id', 'purch_date'])

#Second purchases where first purchase is "3 months subscription"
firstpurch_xmos_and_secpurch = df_all_withxmosPurchFirst_sorted.groupby(
['user_id'], as_index=False).nth(1)
firstpurch_xmos_and_secpurch_frame = firstpurch_xmos_and_secpurch['product'].str.title(    ).value_counts().to_frame(name='second_buy')
```

And that give me output like this showing subsequent purchases of those who initially purchased a 3 Months Subscription:

```
                        second_buy  
3 Months Subscription   23      
6 Months Subscription   18      
12 Months Subscription  16      
1 Month Firecracker Md  3       
24 Months Subscription  3       
2 Months Subscription   3       
18 Months Subscription  3       
36 Months Subscription  2       
9 Months Subscription   1       
48 Months Subscription  1       
2 Month Subscription    0       
18 Months Subscription  0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get your query then you may want how many users purchased a specific product

```
dictionary = {
    'user_id':[65587578,65587578,65587578,65785442,65785442,65785442,89808622,89808622,89808622],
    'purch_date':['2018-03-01 01:21:12','2018-06-07 19:39:56','2019-03-07 11:39:56','2018-03-07 19:39:56'
,'2018-09-07 11:39:16','2019-09-01 10:21:11','2018-03-01 02:19:0','2018-06-07 19:39:56','2019-07-07 12:31:46'],
    'Product': ['3 month subscription','6 month subscription','12 month subscription'
,'3 month subscription'
,'6 month subscription'
,'6 month subscription'
,'3 month subscription'
,'1 month subscription'
,'12 month subscription']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
display(df)

user_id     purch_date           Product
65587578    2018-03-01 01:21:12 3 month subscription
65587578    2018-06-07 19:39:56 6 month subscription
65587578    2019-03-07 11:39:56 12 month subscription
65785442    2018-03-07 19:39:56 3 month subscription
65785442    2018-09-07 11:39:16 6 month subscription
65785442    2019-09-01 10:21:11 6 month subscription
89808622    2018-03-01 02:19:0  3 month subscription
89808622    2018-06-07 19:39:56 1 month subscription
89808622    2019-07-07 12:31:46 12 month subscription

#List of users with a 3-month subscription

df[df['Product']=='3 month subscription']

    user_id     purch_date             Product
0   65587578    2018-03-01 01:21:12 3 month subscription
3   65785442    2018-03-07 19:39:56 3 month subscription
6   89808622    2018-03-01 02:19:00 3 month subscription

#Number of users with a 3-month subscription

(df['Product']=='3 month subscription').sum()
-->3
```

Now other subscriptions they bought. For this, we can use the string functionality of pandas.

```
#This will do the work you want
other = (df.groupby('user_id').sum()['Product'].str.split('3 month subscription',expand=True))
#expand=True makes it in DataFrame else you will get Series
display(other)
    0                              1
user_id     
65587578        6 month subscription12 month subscription
65785442        6 month subscription6 month subscription
89808622        1 month subscription12 month subscription

#More cleaned
other[1].str.split('subscription',expand=True).drop(2,axis=1)

               0        1
user_id     
65587578    6 month 12 month
65785442    6 month 6 month
89808622    1 month 12 month
```

Comment: Thanks Padam. Very kind of you to offer your suggestions. I am running to in to a key error on Product on the real dataframe. I will try work through or around this and incorporate your suggestions. I will let you know early next week.

Comment: Ok @Kierk, I would be very happy if I could help you in any way.

Comment: Thanks again @Padam Gupta. You helped jumpstart my thought process. In the end creating two dataframes and using 'isin' seemed like a logical approach.